# Direct Cartopy feature request to local directories instead of geoserver

Tags: cartopy

If you download the data from:
https://www.naturalearthdata.com/
then is there an option  in  [cartopy.feature](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/feature_interface.html) adds  to check a local directory first before going to the webserver.

I think under windows there is some caching going on in appdata but could not find documentation to provide a path for this feature to look for the data in a directory.  Nor how this would be standardized across OS. This could be applied to the feature request in this cartopy example:

https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/lines_and_polygons/feature_creation.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-and-polygons-feature-creation-py

snippets:

```
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
# Create a feature for States/Admin 1 regions at 1:50m from Natural Earth
states_provinces = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(
    category='cultural',
    name='admin_1_states_provinces_lines',
    scale='50m',
    facecolor='none')
```

Comment: Cartopy always check a local directory first, if the data not already downloaded, it gets from the internet. You can compare by running your code again. The first time it may need to download the data. But the second time, it uses the downloaded data and runs faster. Use this to get the location of the data folder `import cartopy `    then 
`cartopy.config['data_dir']`.

Comment: Thank You. Somehow I missed finding config. https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/cartopy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by swatchai in the comment there is a config class that handles this with fall back to download.
https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/cartopy.html

Comment: You can click to accept your answer. You may earn some reputation points from doing so.